# The Pythonic way to grow a list of lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a large file (2GB) of categorical data (mostly "Nan"--but populated here and there with actual values) that is too large to read into a single data frame.  I had a rather difficult time coming up with a object to store all the unique values for each column (Which is my goal--eventually I need to factorize this for modeling)

What I ended it up doing was reading the file in chunks into a dataframe and then get the unique values of each column and store them in a list of lists.  My solution works, but seemed most un-pythonic--is there a cleaner way to accomplish this in Python (ver 3.5).  I do know the number of columns (~2100).

```
import pandas as pd
#large file of csv separated text data
data=pd.read_csv("./myratherlargefile.csv",chunksize=100000, dtype=str)

collist=[]
master=[]
i=0
initialize=0
for chunk in data:
    #so the first time through I have to make the "master" list
    if initialize==0:
        for col in chunk:
            #thinking about this, i should have just dropped this col
            if col=='Id':
                continue
            else:
                #use pd.unique as a build in solution to get unique values
                collist=chunk[col][chunk[col].notnull()].unique().tolist()
                master.append(collist)
                i=i+1
    #but after first loop just append to the master-list at
    #each master-list element
    if initialize==1:
        for col in chunk:
            if col=='Id':
                continue
            else:
                collist=chunk[col][chunk[col].notnull()].unique().tolist()
                for item in collist:
                    master[i]=master[i]+collist
                i=i+1
    initialize=1
    i=0
```

after that, my final task for all the unique values is as follows:

```
i=0
names=chunk.columns.tolist()
for item in master:
     master[i]=list(set(item))
     master[i]=master[i].append(names[i+1])
     i=i+1
```

thus master[i] gives me the column name and then a list of unique values--crude but it does work--my main concern is building the list in a "better" way if possible.

Comment: have you considered using a generator to lazily read the file? (lookup the yield keyword)

Comment: That might do the trick.  I am not good with iterators and generators yet-- but a cursory glance at the yield keyword as suggested seems to be in the right direction.

Comment: This is actually using a generator under the hood. The chunksize is doing exactly that. Out of curiosity are you running on a 32 or 64 bit machine/python? `import sys; print(sys.maxsize)' should work so long as you are running python 2.6

Comment: im guessing you could probably use something like apache spark to parallelize it if speed is your concern ....

Comment: @ Luke This was 64bit Python 3.5 (8GB mem).  I may have been able to force it into memory, but as I am working to learn "big data" the important thing is to be able to read something bigger than my memory.  This file probably doesn't qualify but it is a good prototype for on my machine at least. 
@Joran Speed wasn't so much a concern it was more "clean code"--my main motivation was to understand the advanced workings of python. This takes about 10 mins for my file, which is really a 1 time operation.

Thank you both for your comments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest instead of a `list` of `list`s, using a [`collections.defaultdict(set)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Say you start with

```
uniques = collections.defaultdict(set)
```

Now the loop can become something like this:

```
for chunk in data: 
    for col in chunk:
        uniques[col] = uniques[col].union(chunk[col].unique())
```

Note that:

1. `defaultdict` always has a `set` for `uniques[col]` (that's what it's there for), so you can skip `initialized` and stuff.
2. For a given `col`, you simply update the entry with the union of the current set (which initially is empty, but it doesn't matter) and the new unique elements.

**Edit**

As Raymond Hettinger notes (thanks!), it is better to use

```
       uniques[col].update(chunk[col].unique())
```

Comment: Wow--that does the trick in 1/3 the code.  I need to work on dicts as well.  Well done.

Comment: @RDS Thanks. I liked your question. All the best.

Comment: This would look nicer with ``set.update`` rather than ``set.union``.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger You're absolutely, correct, thanks! Updated.